# JavaScript Datatable returns no data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datatables

I can see items in datatable but first row is No Data in table ?

```
(document).ready(function() {
  $('#callback_table').DataTable({
    "paging": "input",
    "ajax": {
      "type": "GET",
      "url": '/History/GetCallbackHistory',
      "data": {
        UserId: document.getElementById("callbackuserid").value
      },
      "dataSrc": "",
      "success": function(response) {
        alert("111Done!");
        response.forEach(function(dt) {
          $("#tdata").append("<tr>" +
            "<td>" + dt.Id + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + dt.DateCallback + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + dt.DateEnd + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + dt.Point + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + dt.TaskId + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + typecallback[dt.callbackId] + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + dt.Task_name + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + callbackStatus[dt.callbackStatus] + "</td>" +
            +"</tr>");
        });
      }
    },
  });
  // fillTable(getData());
});
```

Comment: You mis `$` before `(document)` but that might be a copy paste error. Can you show the data used for the datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some notes:

(1) You should not override the `success` option when loading your data using DataTables's `ajax` option. [DataTables uses it](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc), behind the scenes to draw the table.

(2) You should not add rows to DataTables by appending data to the DOM like you are doing. DataTables knows nothing about this data.

Note (2) explains why you can see your data - you added it to the web page.

Note (1) explains why DataTables is reporting "no data in table": it is stuck trying to load the data.

I expect you would see related errors in your browser's console, also (hit F12 to access it).

So, instead, you can use DataTables built-in JSON data loader. Start by deleting the `success` section from your DataTables `ajax` option. That may be all you need to do, or you may hit a new problem, depending on how your JSON is structured and how your table columns are defined.

There are lots of examples in the documentation. [This](https://datatables.net/manual/ajax) is a good overview. There are more detailed examples [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/index.html).

In your case, you provide the `"dataSrc": ""` option - so that means DataTables expects your JSON response to be an unnamed array: `[ ...data... ]`.